# Duplicate image shown - useEffect issue?

Tags: reactjs

I have some code to display my board as shown below:

```
 <Grid item xs={6} justify="center">
    <Paper id="board">
    </Paper>
 </Grid>
```

But sometimes when I save my code, it displays a duplicate board on the screen on localhost:3000, although not always. Example below:

[image: Double image issue]

I am suspecting it it might have something to do with my useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // componentDidMount() {
    const board = new Gameboard(document.getElementById('board'), {
      // position: 'r4r1k/p1P1qppp/1p6/8/5B2/2Q1P3/P4PPP/R3KB1R b KQ - 0 21',
      position: game.fen(),
      sprite: {
        url: './gameboard-sprite.svg', // pieces and markers are stored as svg in the sprite
        grid: 40, // the sprite is tiled with one piece every 40px
        cache: true,
      },
      orientation: COLOR.white,
      moveInputMode: MOVE_INPUT_MODE.dragPiece,
      responsive: true,
    });
    board.enableMoveInput(inputHandler);
  }, []);
```

Any idea why it could be displaying twice, but only sometimes? It always removes the duplicate board when I click the browser refresh button if that helps. But it is often there when I first save my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your Gameboard instance in `useRef`, this way only one instance is created:

```
const board = useRef(); 

useEffect(() => {
    if(!board.current) {
      board.current = new Gameboard(document.getElementById('board'), {
        // position: 'r4r1k/p1P1qppp/1p6/8/5B2/2Q1P3/P4PPP/R3KB1R b KQ - 0 21',
        position: game.fen(),
        sprite: {
          url: './gameboard-sprite.svg', // pieces and markers are stored as svg in the sprite
          grid: 40, // the sprite is tiled with one piece every 40px
          cache: true,
        },
        orientation: COLOR.white,
        moveInputMode: MOVE_INPUT_MODE.dragPiece,
        responsive: true,
      });
      board.current.enableMoveInput(inputHandler);
    }
 }, []);
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying "Const declarations require an initialization value. It is highlighting the dot between board and current here: `const board.current = `

Comment: Where are you using const board.current = ??? should be const board = useRef(). and update it value board.current = some value

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear. I am getting the error on this line of code: `const board.current = new Gameboard(document.getElementById('board'), {` and it is pointing to the dot between board and current.

Comment: Wait, I've just noticed something. You removed the const at the beginning of that line and I missed it. I cannot get the dupe now, so I think it is solved! It was a big nuisance and now it is gone! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) from effect, so when fast refresh will rerun it, there will be no duplicates. It works properly *sometimes* because sometimes fast refresh *sometimes* don't try to preserve state and renders everything as new. This depends on changes you made, so when you change one file it will render clean, but on another files it will try to preserve state and only rerun effects (this is where second board added).

Also, it is better not to interact with DOM directly and use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) instead. This is better way to work with DOM in react, since it's react main purpose to update DOM.